# Run Submit Button on inital page load

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have a table using the variables from the below drop down menu.  When the user selects the option in the drop down the table pulls the information based on the variable tied to the selection.  How ever when the page first loads it errors out saying the query is missing the variable from the drop down.  If I make a selection from the drop down it refreshes the page and resolves the issue. I need the drop down to initially submit the data or whatever is necessary for the query to get its variable on intial page load.

```
$selected = 'selected = "selected" ';
$Country =$ID_SOCIEDAD;
echo "<form name='country_list' method='POST' action='http://opben.com/colombia/familias-de-carteras' >";

echo "<select name='Country' tabindex='1' >";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

                echo " <option  ".($row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code'] == $Country? $selected : '')."value='". $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Code'] ."'>". $row['Fund_Manager_Company_Name'] ."</option>";

                  }
       echo "     </select>
    <input type='submit' value='Filter' />";
 echo "   </form>
```

Here is the sql query for the drop down menu options:

```
$result = mysql_query("

 SELECT 
 ID_SOCIEDADADM as Fund_Manager_Company_Code,   
 DES_SOCIEDAD_CORTO as Fund_Manager_Company_Name


FROM dr_lista_rentabilidad_diaria

GROUP BY ID_SOCIEDADADM
")

  or die(mysql_error());
```

Here is the query for the table:

```
   $result = mysql_query("
      SELECT 
  ID_CARTERA as Fund_ID,
      DES_CARTERA_CC as Fund_Name,
      DES_CARTERACLASE as Class_Name,
      DES_CARTERACLASE_ESP as Special_Class_Name,
      FORMAT(POR_RENTCARTERA_C1,2) AS Yield_1month

      FROM dr_lista_rentabilidad_diaria
      WHERE COD_PAIS       = $COD_PAIS
      AND   ID_SOCIEDADADM = $ID_SOCIEDAD
      AND   `ID_COLUMNA_C1`= $ID_COLUMNA
      ORDER BY DES_CARTERA_CC ASC

  ")

       or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: "...If I make a selection from the drop down it refreshes the page and resolves the issue..." Is it refreshing via javascript/ajax or loading another (different) page?

Comment: Please show us your SQL query.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't post your query, so it is hard to give an appropriate answer. However, my guess is that you have the variable $_POST['Country'] somewhere in that query. So why don't you do this:

```
$country = $_POST['Country'];
if (!isset($country)) { $country = 'US'; }

$query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE country = ' . $country;
```

EDIT: As BenM (correctly) pointed out, this code snippet is absolutely not save. You should NOT include this in your production code. It was just meant to give you an idea on how to avoid the SQL error you are getting by always providing a valid value for the country.

Comment: Because that's a massive SQL injection hole?!

Comment: Of course it is. But I am trying to fix the OPs issue with the (non-existing) info given and based on his previous questions. If I were to solve his problem AND make sure it doesn't have holes, I would have to write a book. :)

Comment: What I am trying to say is: The OP's knowledge of PHP/SQL/form submission is so limited, that I am trying to help him with the most immediate problem and don't (yet) worry about fixing everything.